# Applying new operator to Shape.call(o)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call function via `call` property. Consider the following code

```
function Shape(){
    this.x=0;
    this.y=0;
}
var o={p:'p'};
new Shape.call(o);
```

I have an error

```
[03:02:19.124] TypeError: Shape.call is not a constructor @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:40
```

But i'm excepted that after applying `new` operator to `Shape.call(o)` an empty object will be created. Further `this` will indicate to `o` and after execution `Shape.call(o)` we have that `o={p:'p',x=0,y=0}`.

```
alert(typeof (Shape.call));//function
```

My question is:
Why `new` operator cant apply to `Shape.call(o)`

Comment: @Felix Kling I'm repeat what's interesting for me. **Why** I cant to use new in this case?

Comment: Well, you didn't ask that. Will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @Felix Kling I'm updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to apply the function to the object, you don't have to use `new`. Just do `Shape.call(o)`.

If you wanted `o` to also inherit from `Shape.prototype`, then you cannot go this path anyway. There is no standard way to change the prototype of an existing object. You could either pass `o` as argument to `Shape` and copy the properties or use `Object.create`:

```
var o = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
o.p = 'p';
Shape.call(o);
```

---

> Why I cant to use new in this case?

`new Shape.call(o)` is evaluated as `(new Shape.call)(o)`. [The new operator throws an error](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.2) if the operand (`Shape.call`) doesn't have an internal `[[Constructor]]` property:

> If *constructor* does not implement the `[[Construct]]` internal method, throw a `TypeError` exception.

Usually every function has this internal property, but [the specification explicitly states](http://es5.github.io/#x15):

> None of the built-in functions described in this clause that are not constructors shall implement the `[[Construct]]` internal method unless otherwise specified in the description of a particular function.

[`Function.prototype.call`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4) is a built-in function, not a constructor, and hence doesn't have a `[[Construct]]` property.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for exhaustive answer!